# How to switch between speaker and headphones in iPad application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, avaudiosession

I am writing a function that switches the audio to the speaker:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

But when I try to switch it back to the Headphones using this:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

This code works well in iPhone but in iPad it is not switching from speaker to Headphones, Is there any difference can any one guide?

Comment: Shouldn't you be deactivating the session to change properties, then reactivating? Have you tried using the AVAudioSession API? The c-api is deprecated. What versions of iOS are you running on the two devices?

Comment: Running iOS7 for both

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback` to `UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord`in both